# Error : unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm working on a React project and I wanted to install react testing library using the command `npm install --save-dev @testing-library/react`. But unfortunately, I'm getting the following error.   [image]

Here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "description": "Sample Shopping Cart to Explore using RTK",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "peers": "^0.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "^29.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "vite": "^2.3.5"
  }
}
```

My node version is `v18.14.0`. Can someone help me in this issue?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As written in the logs by npm, the version of @testing-library/react that you are trying to install requires React 18.

Comment: Even though upgraded to React 18, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you update both `react` and `react-dom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `@testing-library/react` found `React 17` installed but prefers `React 18`. You can either upgrade to 18, which is not possible for some at the moment.

In that case, try simply using `@testing-library/react@12.`

They dropped support for React 17 in their `v13.0.0` release and announced a breaking change:

https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases/tag/v13.0.0

The downside to using `@testing-library/react@12` is you will need to reference old documentation because you won't have the benefit of v13+ releases.

Hope this helps!